# View component taghelper with areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to have two components with the same name but in different areas.

My component is called C1

The two areas are A1 and A2

A view component class exists in each of the corresponding namespaces

- MyProject.Areas.A1.ViewComponents in the file ./Areas/a1/c1ViewComponent.cs
- MyProject.Areas.A2.ViewComponents in the file ./Areas/a2/c1ViewComponent.cs

The code compiles; however when I try to add my component to a page with a tagheper:

```
<div class="component-container c1" id="system-a1-c1">
  <vc:c1></vc:c1>
</div>
```

It fails to distinguish between the two components as they have the same name and it cannot resolve the path

So I have watched/read a lot of stuff on taghelpers but nothing seems to mention how to use them with areas

1. Is it possible to achieve the effect I am after?
2. What needs to change in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to reference `ViewComponent`.

- Invoke a componenet by `@Component.InvokeAsync`
- Invoking a view component as a Tag Helper

For `<vc:c1></vc:c1>`, you could not specify which the viewcomponent which means it will fail to know which one to use.

You could try `@Component.InvokeAsync` which could refer the ViewComponent by `type`.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(MVCPro.Areas.Admin.ShareViewComponent))
@await Component.InvokeAsync(typeof(MVCPro.Areas.User.ShareViewComponent))
```